# How to instantiate usable objects from strings only known at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Imagine I am making a game, and I have metadata about characters in my game stored in some sort of plaintext config file:

```
class=Orc,hitpoints=10
class=Ghoul,hitpoints=8
```

Something like that. Maybe XML. In my code, I have corresponding classes:

```
class Orc
{
    int hitpoints;
...
}
```

I want to be able to parse such a config file at some arbitrary time during runtime, and create objects. Imagine the use case of loading a save file. I am easily able to create such objects using Activator.CreateInstance:

```
// pretend we parse the enemy type from the config to string enemytype here
object Enemy = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(enemytype));
```

But the problem is these objects are not really usable. Despite the fact that

```
Enemy.GetType()
```

returns 'Orc', methods inside those objects are not accessible.

```
Enemy.hitpoints
```

complains " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'hitpoints' ", because it knows nothing at compile time. 
And I can't just cast to the right type because if I knew the right type at compile time I wouldn't have needed to make an object this way to begin with. So how do you make such objects usable as their actual type? Or is this simply a bad way to solve this problem? My original goal was to avoid hard-coding all sorts of conditional logic to create these objects, and just generate things on the fly from the parsed strings. The other option I can think of is to use a giant switch statement to select based on the parsed string, but that feels yucky.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for how to do [`Serialization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/). There are a lot of ways to do that; XML and JSON are some common ones.

Comment: Use serialization (XML/JSON) if your objects are complex (contains lists of lists, other classes within, etc.). If they're pretty simple (only a bunch of top level properties), you can even use CSV files.

Comment: As others have said Serialization will work for saving/loading data from files. But the reason your `Enemy.hitpoints` is not accessible is because you have it scoped as private, meaning it's only accessible from within the `Orc` class. The simple answer is you need to make any fields and properties you want to access outside of your `Enemy` class as public, e.g. `Public int hitpoints;`

Comment: "Or is this simply a bad way to solve this problem?"...

Yes.

The question is: why are you creating strongly typed objects for all your different monsters? Why not simply a monster type with properties and methods that describe that monster and its behavior?

Comment: If you're not too experienced with C#, you'd better stay away from these kind of complex challenges. In this case, you're trying to access a property that doesn't seem to exist in the class. Or the property is defined as private and thus not available outside the class. In your code, enemy is an "object" object so none of the non-object methods would not be visible. You might have to use 'var' instead of 'object'. But that's hard to tell with this small amount of info.

Comment: It's not just a scoping issue. Even with `hitpoints` set as public in the `Orc` class, it doesn't work because at compile time it does not know that `Enemy` is of type `Orc` at all. Thank you for the comments on serialization. And yes I am new to C# so I am open to any suggestions on how to structure this better.

Comment: @S.Brentson Yes you are right, this is probably the best way to clean up my code. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, If what you're looking to do is be able to save and load instances of enemies, serialisation is the way to go.
Try the following link for a basic how to of [serialisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization).

Just for the purpose of learning things / experimenting: To make your current implementation work, all enemy objects would need to implement an interface which you could cast the result of Activator.CreateInstance to at compile time. e.g.:

```
public interface IEnemy
{
    int Hitpoints { get; set; }
...
}

public class Orc : IEnemy
{
    public int Hitpoints { get; set; }
...
}

public class Ghoul : IEnemy
{
    public int Hitpoints { get; set; }
...
}
```

and then the call to create the instance becomes:

```
// pretend we parse the enemy type from the config to string enemytype here
IEnemy enemy = (IEnemy)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(enemytype));
```

At which point you can access any methods and properties on the interface which are specified as common to all the enemies.

It should be noted that if the type of enemy created by the activator were to not implement IEnemy, your program would throw an InvalidCastException.

Regardless of your final implementation, it is almost certain that having an IEnemy interface to allow abstraction over what type of enemy an object is and provide common functionality will prove useful.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for both showing how to make my implementation work, as well as suggesting a better strategy.